# Calculate range of object using Azimuth and Elevation

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I have a camera that gives Azimuth and Elevation of an object with respect to itself (camera). The camera doesn't send image but Azimuth and Elevation data (in float format). The camera doesn't provide range.
Is their a mathematical way for me to calculate the range of the said object using Azimuth and Elevation.
I wish to use this data received for camera in sensor fusion algorithm along with LIDAR data. For this I need range of the object.

Comment: You need one additional measure.

Comment: @Moti Can you elaborate on what is the one additional measure I need.

Comment: Example - known size of one dimension of the object you scan or two measures at different locations/times. The best option for LIDAR is using the concept of gated TV.

Comment: number of companies that use gated TV with LIDAR today. Some of these companies include: Velodyne Lidar, Quanergy Systems, Hesai Technology, Innoviz Technologies, and Luminar Technologies